# How to express "at least one" or "at least some" (of a countable or uncountable collection respetively), as in antivacuous statements?

Tags: phrase-requests, semantics, logic, grammatical-roles

Discrete (countable) case example: All/Some of the trees on this block are oak. [And there is at least one oak tree on the block, but possibly two or more.]

Continuous (uncountable) case example: All/Some of the milk in the fridge is spoiled. [And at least some small volume of milk remains in said fridge.]

Note that "all" typically entails "some", unless interpreting 'some' as "some but not all" (more than none but less than all) instead of "at least some" (up to all). The semantic intent here is to leave it intentionally ambiguous, in a similar way that "sheep" can refer to a singular sheep or multiple sheep (whereas 'single sheep' vs 'sheeps' is a possible resolution where explication is desired), as contrasted to 'cat' vs 'cats' (or 'tree' vs 'trees') which can have the opposite potential problem trying to be addressed.

At any rate, I'm wondering how linguistically to express existence unto some *object or objects* (quantity = cardinality or amount := >0) possessing a common set of characteristic[s].  I am also wondering if there is an optimal way to express similar concept with a vacuous existence status explicitly, e.g. "Some\All our milk from last month is spoiled [although there might not be any of said milk remaining]". **edit:** "Some/Any milk remaining from last month is spoiled." I think does the job. Some↦Some, All↦Any  :⇔ (either Some or All) ↦ (either Some or Any).  I'll try to think of more ambiguous case for necessitating "assertively vacuous" need. In the meanwhile, the "assertively non-vacuous" dilemma is the main concern.